# Possible to Integrate IOS app with ERC20 token

Tags: ios, swift, ethereum, erc20

Is is possible at this point to integrate an IOS app with an ERC20 token on the ethereum network.

There seems to be a library called [web3.swift](https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/introducing-web3-swift-for-ethereum-ios-development-1e02212b662b) that allows for integration with Ethereum. Maybe this is the way to go but don't know if it is ready for a production app.

In addition, there seem to be some online courses on Swift and blockchain such as [this one from Lynda](https://www.lynda.com/Web-Development-tutorials/Blockchain-Programming-iOS-Using-Swift/779750-2.html) and [this one from Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/blockchain-programming-in-ios-using-swift/) and some tutorials on blockchain integration such as [this from AppCoda](https://www.appcoda.com/blockchain-introduction/) and [this one](https://learnappmaking.com/blockchain-app-swift-how-to/) which uses the Tierion blockchain as a service. In fact, AWS, Azure and so forth all seem to offer blockchain as a service. Amazon offers managed blockchain with Ethereum.

However, I haven't seen anything that specifically addresses how to integrate an IOS app with Ethereum. And if it's done on the back end by AWS does this defeat the purpose of using a blockchain to avoid centralization on a server?

The use case I am examining would be to view the number of tokens you have and enable users to spend tokens on services. The tokens would reside however on a blockchain.

Thanks for any advice on whether this is even possible at this stage and, if so, how to approach developing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New transaction

[Infura](https://infura.io) service might help here. Once you create your account and setup a project - you will be provided with nodes (for main-net and some test-nets) that can perform write operations on a specific Ethereum network.

Here is the code written in Swift and [Web3.swift](https://github.com/Boilertalk/Web3.swift) that might help:

```
func send(sender: String,
          receiver: String,
          senderSecret: String,
          tokenContractAddress: String,
          amount: Int,
          completion: @escaping Result<Transaction, Error>) {

    let web3 = Web3(rpcURL: "YOUR_INFURA_NODE_ID_GOES_HERE")

    do {
        let privateKey = try EthereumPrivateKey(hexPrivateKey: senderSecret)

        let senderWallet = try EthereumAddress(hex: sender, eip55: true)

        let receiverWallet = try EthereumAddress(hex: receiver, eip55: true)

        let contract = web3.eth.Contract(
            type: GenericERC20Contract.self,
            address: try EthereumAddress(hex: tokenContractAddress, eip55: true)
        )

        firstly {
            return web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address: privateKey.address, block: .latest)
        }.compactMap { nonce in
            guard let tx = contract
                .transfer(to: receiverWallet, value: BigUInt(amount))
                .createTransaction(
                    nonce: nonce,
                    from: senderWallet,
                    value: 0,
                    gas: 100000,
                    gasPrice: EthereumQuantity(quantity: 21.gwei)
                ) else { return nil }

            return try tx.sign(with: privateKey, chainId: 3)
        }.then { tx in
            return web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(transaction: tx!)
        }.done { hash in
            let tx = Transaction(hash: hash)
            completion.set(.success(tx))
        }.catch { error in
            completion.set(.failure(error))
        }
    } catch {
        completion.set(.failure(error))
    }
}
```

## Open information

If there is no need to initiate transactions and you just want to work with public information like **token supply/holder balances/etc.** - you can try some open API like [blockscout](https://blockscout.com/) to get the data you need.